# Function trying to return two pointers for %d

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to return 2 pointers from this function that swaps their values and display them on the screen. The problem is, I'm keep getting a compiler error saying I can't return ints in a void type function. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

```
void numberSwap(int *number1, int *number2);

int main()
{
   int x,
       y;

   scanf("%d%d", x, y);

   printf("before swap: %d and %d", x, y);
   printf("after swap:  %d and %d", numberSwap(&x, &y));

   return(0);
}

void numberSwap(int *number1, int *number2)
{
   int t;

   t        = *number1;
   *number1 = *number2;
   *number2 = t;

   return
}
```

Comment: For a start, you can't return ints in a void type function.

Comment: So should I change it to an int function and should that work?

Comment: Will that help? You can only return one int from an int function. But it's strange, because in your code you are not returning anything from any function (except for main).

Comment: Code shown doesn't return an int. In fact it doesn't compile due to a missing semicolon after `return`

Comment: Paul, `scanf("%d%d", x, y);` expects `x,y` to be `int *`, not `int`.  What compiler are you using that does not warn about that?

Comment: No offense, but it's really time to start reading your C text book.

Answer (score 5):

You're using the function `numberSwap` in an expression that is expecting an `int` (i.e. as a parameter to `printf`), but the function's return type is `void`.  That's what is causing the error.

You just need to call the function in a statement by itself.  When it returns, `x` and `y` will have been updated, so you can print them then.

```
   printf("before swap: %d and %d", x, y);
   numberSwap(&x, &y);
   printf("after swap:  %d and %d", x, y);
```

You also have a problem here:

```
scanf("%d%d", x, y);
```

As the `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects an `int *` but you pass an `int`.  You need to pass the addresses of `x` and `y`:

```
scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
```